# How to link personal miniconda to group anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have been using a local version of miniconda with a base environment installed at `/users/myname/miniconda`, while my system administrator has now installed anaconda for group use in `/opt/anaconda3` .

I'd like a way to keep my personal version (so that I can play around with packages without pestering my admin) but be able to switch to (i.e. activate) the group environment when needed.

I guess I am looking for something like `conda create -n group_env --clone /opt/anaconda`, but without cloning, just pointing, so that I can run `conda activate group_env` and `conda activate base` to switch back and forth between the two.

Many thanks!
A.

Comment: Have you attempted `conda activate /opt/anaconda3`?

Comment: Thank-you @merv , this worked. I feel a bit dumb that I did not think of it myself, but I obviously do not understand conda environments well enough yet! 

It would be good to know how, as a bonus, if possible, to have conda 'remember' this environment, so that I can give it a name (e.g `group_env`) and have it show up in `conda env list`. 

In any case, if you post your answer `conda activate /opt/anaconda3` I'll be happy to accept :)